# Specify range or Range adress as seriescollection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to dynamically update the source data of a graph with a specified range.

Here is the code i tried :

```
Sub graphs()
    Call ImportData
    Dim epibase As ChartObject
    Set epibase = wst_epibase.ChartObjects("Graphique 3")
    epibase.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & wst_techno.Name & "'!" & wst_techno.Range("B4:B11").Address(False, False)
    
    
End Sub
```

epibase is the chartobject i assign to my Graph and wst_epibase is the worksheet where the graph is located and wst_techno is the worksheet where the source is located, they are both defined and set correctly and working when used in other subs.

I also tried this but does not work :

```
epibase.SeriesCollection(1).Values = wst_techno.Range("B4:B11")
```

I get error 438 everytime
Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try `"='" & wst_techno.Name & "'!B4:B11"`? Are there spaces in `wst_techno` name? If not, it can be `"=" & wst_techno.Name & "!B4:B11"`. If it does not work, please try `Debug.Print wst_techno.Name`. Does it return the name you are expecting? Where and how did you `Set` the sheet in discussion?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, there was a space in the name, i just changed it and tried both of your solutions but none work.    
Here is the exact name of wst_techno : Techno_(Process_flow), and yes it returns the name i'm expecting. 

I set the sheet in discussion in the Importdata sub used in my code as :  Set wst_techno = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Comment: Then, your problem does not come from this direction... Try `epibase.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values =`. And use any of the tested ways... I did not look to the error description. Apropos, it is not good enough to only supply the error number. **Its description would be much more relevant**, at least in my opinion...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.values    Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:T5")

Comment: Hello, thank you both for your help, i added the .chart and specifying the range as values worked perfectly ! 
Here is the line for anyone finding the post : 
```
epibase.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = wst_techno.Range("B4:B9")